# Can a finite ring be ordered?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a ring $R$ with characteristic $\text{char}(R)=n$. Can the elements of this ring be well ordered? If not, what additional properties are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a set, sure, why not? Every finite set can be well ordered.

As an ordered ring, no. If $0< r$, then add $r$ to both sides $m-1$ times so that $m$ is minimal with respect to making $mr=0$. This  yields $(m-1)r<0$, a contradiction, since $r< 2r< \ldots< (m-1)r$

> If not, what additional properties are required?

Since being an ordered ring is already inconsistent with the axioms of a finite ring, adding more requirements *will not help*.

Comment: Ah very nice, so it follows that only rings of infinite characteristic can be ordered (such as $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: @AlexSiryj yes, since $0< 1$, repeated use of the ordering axiom gives an image of $\Bbb Z$ in an ordered ring.

Comment: Wow, that's a beautiful explanation

Comment: @AlexSiryj i am flattered, thank you :)